# How to convert imagedata() to character array while using javacv?

Tags: java, javacv

My code is the following :

```
int compare(IplImage img1, IplImage img2)
{
    int c=img1.nChannels();
    int h= img1.height(); 
    int w= img1.width(); 
    int step= img1.widthStep();
    int step2=img2.widthStep();
    int nc=w*c;
    int i,j,a=0;
    char data[]= (char)img1.imageData();
    char data1[]= (img2.imageData());
    if(step==step2)
        for(i=0;i<=h;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<nc;j+=c)
            {
                if((int)(data[j]+data[j+1]+data[j+2])==0  &&  (int)(data1[j]+data1[j+1]+data1[j+2])==0)
                    a++;
        }
    …
```

I want `imagedata` to return a char array, but I am getting a `com.google.javacpp.bytepointer` type. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please explain more what you want to do and what is exact problem?

Comment: nikhil how can i use the data[] array in the above code when imagedata function in javacv returns a "com.google.javacpp.bytepointer" ?? i am comparing rgb values of two images in the following loops ... plzz help

Comment: There _are_ `BytePointer.get(byte[])` and `BytePointer.put(byte[])` methods if this is what you are looking for?